# Why this assembly binding succeeded?

Tags: .net, .net-assembly

Usually questions about assembly binding are related to a missing assembly. This time I'd like to know why this bind **worked**: It was looking for `ServiceStack.Common, Version=1.0.4356.8984` but it loaded `1.0.4356.6807`

**Why?**

- Are non signed assemblies only matched for mayor.minor version numbers?
- Is the build version (fourth number) always ignored.

It baffles me as VisualStudio is not detecting this file due to incorrect version number but the .NET runtime loads it.

**Notes**: This log is from fuslogvw and I've changed some long/private paths to "...".

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (7/12/2011 @ 10:11:13 πμ) ***

The operation was successful.
Bind result: hr = 0x0. The operation completed successfully.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows...64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\.....CLR4.MSIL.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = MYDOMAIN\me
LOG: DisplayName = ServiceStack.Common, 
     Version=1.0.4356.8984, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///.../bin/Debug
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = C:\...\AppData\Local\Temp\wn3bbgg5.px5
LOG: AppName = MyApp.Tests.Unit
Calling assembly : ServiceStack, 
     Version=3.0.9.8993, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: 
     D:\....Tests.Unit.dll.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from 
     C:\...64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL 
     file:///.../bin/Debug/ServiceStack.Common.DLL.
LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: 
     D:\...\bin\Debug\ServiceStack.Common.dll
LOG: Entering download cache setup phase.
LOG: Assembly Name is: ServiceStack.Common, 
     Version=1.0.4356.6807, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
LOG: Binding succeeds. Returns assembly from    
     C:\...\6868981a_1db4cc01\ServiceStack.Common.dll.
LOG: Assembly is loaded in default load context.
```

Comment: Curious how did you get this error? is this via NuGet? did you have an earlier version of ServiceStack.Common?

Comment: I got Service stack 3.09 from github. Visual Studio refuses to copy the common.dll as it doesn't have the version it expects. But .NET works as a charm. The question here is "why" it works. Currently I "suspect" that it ignores the build version part for unsigned assemblies. But I don't have any reference for this.

Comment: ahh cool, doesn't sound like a common prob then :)

Comment: Only minor problems with VS, nothing serious.